# Simplifying equation into Newton Raphson form

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, roots

> Given the equation $\displaystyle{\int_{-x}^x\exp({-t^2})dt}=-\ln(x)$:
>
> a. Simplify the integral using Gauss method with 3 points.
>
> b. Solve given equation by Newton Raphson iterative method

I succeeded simplifying the integral and got $\int\exp(-t^2)=\frac 8 9 +\frac {10} 9 e^{-0.36x^2}$ but I NR method required function (since the form of $x_{k+1}=x_k+\frac{f(x_k)}{f\prime(x_k)}$) which I haven't found yet here in $-\ln(x)=\frac 8 9 +\frac {10} 9 e^{-0.36x^2}$. which elements should I take to be my $f(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not check the first part , but I think there is an issue as we should be able to validate the LHS and RHS when we find our $x$, and that is not checking out. Note, you formula did not specify which Gauss method to use and that normally means Gauss-Legendre which use Legendre Polynomials as $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 f(x)~dx$ and then use a suitable transformation over $a, b$.

However, here is the process for part b that you are asking about.

$$\displaystyle f(x) = \ln(x)+\frac 8 9 +\frac {10} 9 e^{-0.36x^2}$$

Now, set-up your iteration formula for NR, choose a starting point and find $x$.

A plot shows and approximate location:

[image]

The iteration is given by:

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \dfrac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$$

I chose $x_0 = 0.4$ and got $x = 0.13634195512062696$.

You can verify that at that value of $x$:

$$-\ln(x)=\frac 8 9 +\frac {10} 9 e^{-0.36x^2}$$

However, using a numerical integrator on the LHS with that value of $x$, does not match the RHS, $-\ln x$, so the Gaussian Quadrature result likely has an issue.

Using Cipra's update, we have:

$$\displaystyle f(x) = \ln(x)+ \frac 8 9 x +\frac {10} 9 e^{-3/5 x^2}x$$

A plot shows:

[image]

Using NR, with $x_0 = 0.4$ results in $x = 0.4386233081179400$, which checks out for both sides of:

$$\displaystyle{\int_{-x}^x\exp({-t^2})dt}=-\ln(x)$$

Comment: Nice and thorough answer! +1

Comment: @amWhy: This is a nice problem as it brings together two different techniques in numerical analysis (integration and root) and just looked interesting. Still have not heard from the OP either, so not sure it makes sense yet. :-) Have a great day!

Comment: @Amzoti: You did a good survey Amzoti in this problem :+)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is rewrite the integral using the change of variable $t=ux$ and *then* using [Gauss quadrature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature) to get

$$\int_{-x}^x \exp(-t^2)dt= x\int_{-1}^1 \exp(-x^2u^2)du = x\left({8\over9}+{10\over9}e^{-3x^2/5} \right)$$

Now letting

$$f(x)=\ln x+{8\over9}x+{10\over9}xe^{-3x^2/5}$$

the Newton-Raphson approach shown in Amzoti's answer should produce a better approximate solution.

Note:  If the problem hadn't asked for Gauss quadrature, I would have simply noted that $x$ must lie between $0$ and $1$ (since $-\ln x$ starts at $\infty$ and drops to $0$ while the integral starts at $0$ and becomes positive) and then let

$$\int_{-x}^x \exp(-t^2)dt=\int_{-x}^x(1-t^2+{t^4\over2}-{t^6\over6}+\cdots)dt\approx2(x-{1\over3}x^3+{1\over10}x^5-{1\over42}x^7)$$

Note that the power series expansion for $e^{-3x^2/5}$ leads to

$$x\left({8\over9}+{10\over9}e^{-3x^2/5} \right)\approx 2x-{2\over3}x^3+{1\over5}x^5-{1\over25}x^7$$

so these agree (as they should) for the first few terms.